# "a couple of things" in a formal letter?

Tags: formality, letter-writing

Is it inadequate to use "a couple of things" in a formal letter?  If so, what word or phrase would work better?

Example:

> I`m writing to inquire about a couple of things regarding my new job placement.

Comment: We'll need a bit more context to answer this.

Comment: e.g. "I`m writing to inquire about a couple of things regarding my new job placement." or "I would like to inquire about a couple of things in regards to my new job placement" .

Comment: Have you checked a thesaurus?  You need to share with us where you got stuck. // *Details* is what I'd use.  You could also use *particulars* but that might sound too stuffy in the US.

Answer (score 1):

'a couple of things' may not be appropriate in formal letters, especially because of the word 'things' which is used for everything without a specific meaning. I would recommend using 'a few/several/a couple of aspects/ issues',  and if possible use a specific word that describes and substitutes 'things'.

Eg: We discussed a few demands, which are relevant for us.

Compare with: We discussed a couple of things which are relevant for us.

Register varies.

Comment: I thought so, thank you for the clarification.